# Sound on html5 not work after compile android apk using webview eclips and SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, html, webview

I tried build application for children with mp3 music , using eclipse + SDK with WebView script . apk compile after I try to run , when I press the button to run mp3 sound does not appear ???

this is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.myapp.soundanimal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webview;
    WebSettings websettings;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        websettings=webview.getSettings();

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }    
}
```

and this my html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MY app</title>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="assets/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">             
        <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:20px;" class="mainbox col-md-12 ">                    
            <div class="panel panel-info" > 
                <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >
                <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
                <div align="center">    
                    <img src="assets/image-app/cat.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236"> 
                </div>      
                </br></br></br>                 
                <div align="center">

                    <audio id="myaudio" src="assets/sound-app/suara-anak-kucing.mp3"></audio>   
                    <a href="index.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('myaudio').play()" class="btn btn-warning">Play <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span></button>                 
                    <a href="3.html" data-transition="slide" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

                </div>
                </br></br></br>                        
                </div>  
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>  
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how the audio file is referenced.

You cannot load local files like this from WebView. You can try file://assets/sound-app/suara-anak-kucing.mp3 or serving the mp3 from a local server at home.

Comment: thanks @Miguel Garcia, i try calling mp3 in html, how to call mp3 from local server?